# Laravel - Create file with specific user, group and permissions

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5.4

I try to create a file by using `put` and give the file the permission `777`.

If I create the File like this:

```
use File;

...

$content = "<?php echo 'test'; ?>";
$file   = app_path() . '/Http/Controllers/test.php';
File::put($file, $content);
```

However, the file is created with this rights:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 daemon daemon 2,2K Mär 14 08:08 test.php
```

Also the user and group is `daemon` instead of `root`.

How can I create a file with user and group `root` and with permissions `rwxrwxrwx` ?

e.g.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2,2K Mär 14 08:08 test.php
```

---

I also added these lines to my `/etc/sudoers`

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod 
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chgrp
```

But I still get `chmod(): no permission` with the following code:

```
File::chmod($unitPath, 0777);
chown($unitPath,"root");
chgrp($unitPath,"root");
```

Comment: You will have to exec linux command with `shell_exec` for example.

Comment: why do you use File::put and not fopen or file_put_content

Comment: @AnnSophieAngermüller, because it is faster to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `shell_exec()`

```
shell_exec('sudo chmod 0777 '. $unitPath);
shell_exec('sudo chown root:root '. $unitPath);
```

Make sure that `www-data` is allowed to execute the commands by entering these lines in the file `/etc/sudoers`.

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod 
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown
```

**Important**! Always use `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers` otherwise you can easily make syntax errors and corrupt the file and loose the possibilty to use `sudo`, and you need to fix your system by booting from a live cd.

Comment: giving  sudo access to www-data is great security risk.

Answer (score 5):

Laravel has built-in support for changing mod

ex:

```
File::chmod($file,0755); //the leading zero is a must
```

Unfortunately it doesn't has chown in its Filesystem module, but you can call the php one

```
chown($file,"root");
```

to change the group

```
chgrp($file,"group");
```

Note that : changing group and owner will fail if you're not a super user, even if you can sudo.

Comment: I tried it and I always get `chmod() no permission`
I also added this to my **/etc/sudoers**. 
`www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chgrp
`